# View Frustum Culling Quad

Tags: webgl, frustum

I'am trying to apply view frustum culling to my scene.
I basically have this setup:

- Rendering one quad displayed as Quadtree
- For example if depth is `1` then the quad gets split into 4 smaller quads
- Each quad has a texture
- I have a first person camera, which means I can only look around but not move (the orogin of my camera is always at `(0,0,0)`)

The Quad at `depth 1` looks like this:

1---2

3---4

Where `quad 1` represents the `nw quadrant` of the quadtree, `quad 2` the `ne quadrant` of the quadtree and so on.
My goal is (for example `depth 1`) that whenever I move my camera and for example `quad 1` and `3` are not visible anymore, they should not be rendered anymore.

However my current implementation is not correct. I'am extracting the `frustumplanes` like this and I think this the error.

```
createFrustumPlanes(vp) {

    let leftPlane = vec4.fromValues(vp[0] + vp[3], vp[4] + vp[7], vp[8] + vp[11], vp[12] + vp[15]);
    vec4.normalize(leftPlane, leftPlane);
    let rightPlane = vec4.fromValues(-vp[0] + vp[3], -vp[4] + vp[7], -vp[8] + vp[11], -vp[12] + vp[15]);
    vec4.normalize(rightPlane, rightPlane);
    let bottomPlane = vec4.fromValues(vp[1] + vp[3], vp[5] + vp[7], vp[9] + vp[11], vp[13] + vp[15]);
    vec4.normalize(bottomPlane, bottomPlane);
    let topPlane = vec4.fromValues(-vp[1] + vp[3], -vp[5] + vp[7], -vp[9] + vp[11], -vp[13] + vp[15]);
    vec4.normalize(topPlane, topPlane);
    let nearPlane = vec4.fromValues(vp[2] + vp[3], vp[6] + vp[7], vp[10] + vp[11], vp[14] + vp[15]);
    vec4.normalize(nearPlane, nearPlane);
    let farPlane = vec4.fromValues(-vp[2] + vp[3], -vp[6] + vp[7], -vp[10] + vp[11], -vp[14] + vp[15]);
    vec4.normalize(farPlane, farPlane);
    return [
      leftPlane,
      rightPlane,
      bottomPlane,
      topPlane,
      nearPlane,
      farPlane
    ];
}
```

Where `vp` is the following `this._vpMatrix`:

```
   this._lookAtMatrix = mat4.create();
   mat4.lookAt(this._lookAtMatrix, vec3.fromValues(0, 0, 0), this._lookAtVector, vec3.fromValues(0, 1, 0));
   this._projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
   mat4.perspective(this._projectionMatrix, this._FOV * Math.PI / 180.0, this._width / this._height, 0.001, 50);
   this._vpMatrix = mat4.create();
   mat4.multiply(this._vpMatrix, this._projectionMatrix, this._lookAtMatrix);
```

How are you extracting `frustum planes` and from which `matrix` are the planes created?

Comment: Your frustum plane equation appear correct, but i think the problem is your view matrix, try multiply the lookat by the projection instead of the projection by the lookat...

Comment: No, doesnt work, also I think the order projection*view*model

Comment: I never deeply explored the multiple possible combinations of transform matrices with projection, and I think order depend on how vertices are finaly transformed in the vertex shader. But I always used `lookat*projection` as view matrix (and now I wonder why)... All work fine on my side, my frustrum extraction function is however slightly different, I compute (for example) `view[3] - view[0]` instead of `-view[0] + view[3]`, but, the result is the same.